# How can I get a list of all disabled domain users with group membership, one user per line, but omit results for users that have no membership?

Tags: active-directory, powershell, users, groups

For example, when our users are terminated, we need to remove all groups. I want to check for groups still connected to user, but not show the users where the groups are removed.

I have the following, which shows all disabled users, but can't figure out how to test for a null group. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Import-Module Activedirectory
Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $false' -Properties DisplayName,memberof | % {
New-Object PSObject -Property @{
UserName = $_.DisplayName
Groups = ($_.memberof | Get-ADGroup | Select -ExpandProperty Name) -join 
","}
} | Select UserName,Groups
```

Comment: PLEASE read the Tour page for this site ... and use the code formatting instructions linked on that page. [*grin*]

Comment: All users are a member of at least one group.

Answer (score 1):

Add a where check before the select:

```
| Where-Object {$_.Groups -ne $null} 


Import-Module Activedirectory
Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $false' -Properties DisplayName,memberof | % {
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    UserName = $_.Name
    Groups = ($_.memberof | Get-ADGroup | Select -ExpandProperty Name) -join ","}
} | Where-Object {$_.Groups -ne $null} | Select UserName,Groups
```

Comment: Thanks Greg! This runs, however I'm still seeing blank groups in the output. Do you know a better way to filter this? @GregAskew. Thanks a million btw

Comment: UserName        Groups                                
--------        ------                                
John Lennon     Domain Admins                         
George Harrison                                       
George Martin   Enterprise Admins                     
Brian Epstein